# UIPickerView does not display images correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am implementing a custom picker view only with images. The problem is, the images are overlayed over each other like that:
[image]

This is the code configuring the images in the picker view:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView {
    let chosenImage: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: iconArray[row]))
    NSLog("choosen image \(iconArray[row])")
    let workaroundImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: chosenImage.frame)
    workaroundImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: chosenImage.image!)
    return workaroundImageView
}
```

What am I missing? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize the rowHeightForComponent in the delegate for the UIPickerView.

```
pickerView:rowHeightForComponent:
```

Give the desired row height for component as such.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat
```

Comment: Thank you! Totally forgot about that method! Cheers, mate!

Comment: No problem! Glad it can be of help!